# Get latest file from sftp to local machine

Tags: shell

I need to get the latest file from the sftp to my local machine, I have a concept which is to list the latest file of the target directory in sftp first before getting the listed latest file.

Any command to complete this using linux shell script?

```
file=$(sftp username@servername 'ls -ltr /server/path | tail -n 1')
```

I have used this command to list the latest file but it does not work. I also don't know about the command for getting the listed file, any idea?

Comment: You can use `sftp` (or `scp`, which is more friendly for command-line/shell situations like this) for downloading the file, but not for running an `ls` command like you have.  Instead, you might try "file=$(ssh username@servername 'ls -ltr /server/path' | tail -n1)" or something similar, _i.e._ using `ssh` rather than `sftp`.

Comment: I tried
file=$(ssh username@servername 'ls -ltr /server/path' | tail -n 1)
scp -r username@servername:/path/path/$file /my/home/directory
But seems this worked for listing files but failed to get the latest file. Any error on this commands?
Anyway, thanks for your answer too!

Comment: Please update your post with the above attempts/changes, and add the errors that you encountered.  These updates are best done in the post, not in comments, for future readers of the site.

Comment: Note that when you run `ls` _over `sftp`_, it given you... the sftp command's version of `ls`, not the remote system's version of `ls`. It's by no means guaranteed to support the same options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `ls options` wrong, try:

```
file=$(ssh username@servername 'ls -1tr /server/path' | tail -n 1)
```

You are using the `-l` (lowercase `L` for `long` listing) option instead of using `-1` (*number one*) option (`list one file per line`) This causes your `ls` command to include the *file permissions, file ownership, etc...* which when used as input to `scp` causes the command to fail.

Also, if you are providing a filename to `scp`, you don't need the `-r` (recursive) option. The following should be all you need for your `scp` command. (don't forget to double-quote `"$file"` to prevent word-splitting if there are spaces in the filename)

```
scp username@servername:/path/path/"$file" /my/home/directory
```

Comment: Thanks. I also have same issue. I can't use ssh and have to use sftp. The server to which I have to connect doesn't allow ssh. On the sftp terminal, looks like | (pipe) doesn't work. Any idea on how to get latest file on sftp terminal.

Answer (score 7):

I did face a tough time achieving this. Apparently **tail** is not a valid command when run over sftp console.
And in my case, we had only the server access via SFTP and not over SSH. Hence the solution by https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin didnt work for me as the solution works while executing commands over ssh.

```
//this gives me name of the latest file on SFTP server
fileName=$(echo "ls -1rt" | sftp -oIdentityFile=<pathToKeyFile> username@sftpServer:/remoteDir | tail -1) 

//this fetches the latest file from sftp server
echo "get $fileName" |sftp -oIdentityFile=<pathToKeyFile> username@sftpServer:/remoteDir
```

Wrap the above set of commands in a shell file and it will work smoothly for you.

Hopefully this will save some time and energy and help someone

Comment: This is great. Thank you!

Comment: Happy, if it helped you!!

Comment: There's no such thing as a "sftp console". sftp doesn't _give_ you a console on the remote machine -- it doesn't pass commands to the remote machine at all; instead, it only passes very low-level requests. "Open this file", "read a block from this file", "list contents of this directory" (and returning them not as text, but as a binary data structure which your sftp client is responsible for translating to a format it can display them in), etc. It can't be used to run the remote machine's copy of _any software at all_ -- not even `ls`.

Comment: ...so what happens when you run `ls` in a sftp client is that the client sends the (binary-format) requests over a SSH channel, reads binary-format responses, and then assembles the results into what that sftp client thinks `ls` output should look like.

Comment: Yes, it seems like the sftp interface is severely lacking. I actually have another problem that I want to filter the results, as I am only interested in files that match a particular name. But guess what happens when you do "ls -1rt pattern*" instead of just "ls -1rt"? - the sort orders gets messed up!! 
This is incredible. Using the glob, destroys the sort

Answer (score 0):

To get multiple file names, use the good old backquote:

```
file=`ssh username@servername 'ls -ltr /server/path' | grep "Mar 16"|awk '{print $9'}`
```

This is assuming that you can autologin to the remote.
Post this using these file names, you can again do a sftp

Comment: Please edit your answer as the backtick was interpreted as a markdown formatting

Comment: `$(...)` is the modern syntax for command substitutions. Backticks haven't been good practice since the POSIX sh standard was published in 1991, providing a newer/better replacement.